# Show different HTML code after one visit

Tags: javascript

Only using Javascript, can someone create a html file that uses "XY" html code when the user first visits it, but it should use "ZQ" (so a fully other one) html code after the first visit? So in the second, third, etc. visit of the same user. There could be many users.

**Question**: how would that html file look like? How to do it? Is it possible using only javascript?

Comment: Of the same user, meaning, per browser session right? **Yes!**

Comment: Cookies, localstorage, or serverside logging... Your choice.

Comment: but how to do it? wow you were quick.

Comment: Learn about cookies or localstorage. It is really basic... Detect the state, show/hide the sections to be shown/hidden

Answer (score 1):

You can use either Cookies or `LocalStorage`, where the `LocalStorage` is easier to implement, but requires the latest browser, and users may disable cookies for privacy reasons.

**Cookies**

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

// First Visit
if (getCookie("visited") == null) {
  // XY code.
  alert("XY Code here");
  // set the cookie
  setCookie("visited", "yes", 10);
} else {
  // subsequent visit.
  // ZQ code.
  alert("ZQ Code here");
}
```

**LocalStorage**

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  if (localStorage.getItem("visited") == "yes") {
    // subsequent visit.
    // ZQ code.
    alert("ZQ Code here");
  } else {
    // XY code.
    alert("XY Code here");
    // set the cookie
    localStorage.setItem("visited", "yes");
  }
} else {
  // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
  // Use the above cookie method.
}
```